# How to improve the hibernate query?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have two classes which named A and B. The primary key of B is a field of tab_A.  The mapping xml is like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.fabulous.A" table="tab_A">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="userId" column="user_id" />

        <many-to-one name="B" column="B_id"
            class="com.fabulous.B" unique="true" lazy= "false" cascade="merge">
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And there is another mapping xml which mapping class B to table B.
The query in my application is:

```
session.createQuery("FROM A WHERE id IN (:ids)").setParameterList("ids", ids).list();
```

The parameter is a list of A.id.  The size of list is  100;

When **lazy=true the query time is about 1s**, but about 1 minute will be cost when A.b is applied. Actually B will always be required, so **I close lazy loading. And the query time is about 40s.**

**From hibernate log, hibernate load B from table B one by one but not in a batch. I think if I extract all B.id from table A in a query and then query table B within a batch the total time will be less than 3s.**

But it's not convenience, could anyone help to figure out how to improve the query with hibernate?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not do a join fetch like `FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.B WHERE a.id IN (:ids)`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov  I tried this seems that it works from the hibernate log, the query is `session.createQuery("FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.b WHERE a.id IN (:ids)").setParameterList("ids", ids).list()`, but I can get only one A from the query, actually the size should be 100. Do you know why it happened?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Is it caused by tag `<many-to-one>`?

Comment: Maybe the relationship is optional, then you need a `LEFT JOIN FETCH`

Comment: Thanks very much for saving my days man @ChristianBeikov . Inner join will be good, I lost a char in most of IDs and only one worked just now.

Comment: Could you post your result by "answer the question"? I will set it to be the right answer. @ChristianBeikov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eagerly fetch some relation for a query just do a simple `JOIN FETCH` or `LEFT JOIN FETCH` if the relation is optional like

```
FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.B WHERE a.id IN (:ids)
```